# Converting nested JSON to HTML Table using Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to parse a Nested JSON into an HTML table using public API - `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`. Strangely 0,1,2,3...and-so-on numbers appear on the top. I double checked the API and these numbers are no where to be found there. What I am missing here or overlooking? Here is the runnable html and JavaScript. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Dynamic HTML Table from Any Nested JSON API's response.</h2>
    <button id="foo">Build table</button>
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
        <tbody id="output">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('#foo');
    button.addEventListener('click', fetchData, false);
    function fetchData() {
        button.textContent = 'Loading...';
        button.disabled = true;
        const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    renderNestedJSON(data, outputElement);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }, 500);

    }
    function renderNestedJSON(data, parentElement) {
        for (const key in data) {
            if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
                // If an object - Recursive
                const nestedWhips = document.createElement("td");
                nestedWhips.className = "className";
                parentElement.appendChild(nestedWhips);

                const keyElement = document.createElement("td");
                keyElement.textContent = key + ": ";
                nestedWhips.appendChild(keyElement);

                renderNestedJSON(data[key], nestedWhips);
            } else {
                // Else render it as-is 
                const keyValueElement = document.createElement("tr");
                keyValueElement.textContent = `${key} : ${data[key]}`;
                parentElement.appendChild(keyValueElement);
            }
        }
        button.remove();
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `key` in `for (const key in data) {` would be an array index if `data` is an array - and that data is an array

Comment: Hmmm... how do I get rid of it? Sorry I am still learning JavaScript.

Comment: don't do `keyElement.textContent = key + ": ";` if `Array.isArray(data)` obviously

Comment: Bingo. Yes that did the trick. Thanks a lot @JaromandaX for looking into it and your time. This is what I did - `if (!Array.isArray(data)) {keyElement.textContent = key + ": ";}` is that a correct approach ?

Comment: looks like it is

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be with the object indexes.
try this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Dynamic HTML Table from Any Nested JSON API's response.</h2>
  <button id="foo">Build table</button>
  <div id="output" class="d-flex flex-row"></div>
</body>

<script>
  const button = document.querySelector('#foo');
  button.addEventListener('click', fetchData, false);

  function fetchData() {
    button.textContent = 'Loading...';
    button.disabled = true;
    const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          renderJSONToTable(data, outputElement);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, 500);

  }

  function renderJSONToTable(data, parentElement) {
    data.forEach(obj => {
      const column = document.createElement("div");
      column.classList.add("flex-fill", "me-2", "p-2", "border");
      renderObject(obj, column);
      parentElement.appendChild(column);
    });

    button.remove();
  }

  function renderObject(obj, parentElement) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      const keyValue = document.createElement("div");
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        keyValue.textContent = `${key}:`;
        const nestedObj = document.createElement("div");
        renderObject(obj[key], nestedObj);
        keyValue.appendChild(nestedObj);
      } else {
        keyValue.textContent = `${key}: ${obj[key]}`;
      }
      parentElement.appendChild(keyValue);
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```